# Border animation not functioning on hover. SlideToggle working fine

Tags: jquery, html, colors, jquery-animate, border

I am looking to transform the right border colour of a DIV when another is hovered upon. The solution to getting the slideToggle to work was a little different from what I've read up on so I imagine this solution will be slightly different.

Here is the very longhand code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".articleExpand").hide();

$('.mainArticle').hover(function() {   
     $(this).find('.articleExpand').stop(true,true).slideToggle('medium');
  }); 


$("mainArticle").hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.articleExpand').animate({"borderRightColor" : "#cccccc"}, 300);
});


});
```

As I mentioned the slideToggle is fine but I am not sure how to integrate the animation.

Many thanks all,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of JQuery UI!  (That's what you need to use.)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

"The jQuery UI effects core extends the animate function to be able to animate colors as well. It's heavily used by the class transition feature and it's able to color animate the following properties:

backgroundColor
borderBottomColor
borderLeftColor
borderRightColor
borderTopColor
color
outlineColor
with one of the following combinations:

hex (#FF0000)
rgb (rgb(255,255,255))
names ("black")"

Comment: Of course, that was utterly thoughtless of me. I am trying to keep the site as lean of possible so may well have to think of another way of doing this, if at all.

Thanks Christian.

Comment: Check out the JQuery color plugin -- I've never used it, but I've heard about it:  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color